# Project Lombok breaks Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, lombok

Hey guys I got a problem with lombok. I try to make a phone book with JSF and SpringBoot literally made with this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/developing-jsf-applications-with-spring-boot

I added the Maven dependency for lombok and got no problom with the @Data annotation, but it won't create any getters and setters and so on. I tried what people here on StackOverflow in other questions said and executed the lombok.jar which is located in my Maven repo: C:\Users\anonym.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.16\lombok-1.16.16.jar

It already had the right path and i clicked install. After that I close and open Eclipse but got exit code = 1 because this line will be added:

-javaagent:lombok.jar

And my Eclipse won't open anymore until i deleted this line. But then lombok does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Please have merci I'm a beginner.

Comment: Did you put a copy of `lombok.jar` into the Eclipse directory? (I think the Lombok installer should do this automatically, but maybe there went something wrong with that step.)

Comment: lombok.jar is in my eclipse directory

Comment: You should try installing the latest Lombok release 1.18.4. It has several eclipse-related fixes. If that works, also update your pom to this version.

Comment: You can try to modify your `eclipse.ini` to use the absolute path instead?

Answer (score 1):

When Lombok is installed it adds a path to eclipse.ini file:
-javaagent:<Lombok.jar location in your eclipse installation>

In my case it tried to escape a localized string in the path but since that path is not available on Windows, Eclipse IDE just could not start. After removing the escape and providing the correct path it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, someone comes across this:

For me, I had to remove the path with the -javaagent entry! So after Lombok installation, it addedd correctly this line:

```
-javaagent:C:\dev\tools\Eclipse4.9\(2018-09\)\lombok.jar
```

Which is the correct path to the eclipse location. I didn't figure out if it's the escaping of the parenthesis or the path itself, but after changing the line to:

```
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

now it starts!